# My PDF's are opening in Adobe but not through my browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, events, pdf

I have a web application in ASP.NET with C# and i am having an issue opening some PDF's.

The code looks up the selected ID and pulls the pdf path associated with that ID. The path that is being returned is working, and is correct. For some reason, when I hit open in the browser it says the file is corrupted and cannot be repaired, but when I open it in adobe everything is perfect.

Here is my code:

```
string id;
string path;

DataTable dt = Session["UnmatchedItems"] as DataTable;

ASPxButton button = (ASPxButton)sender;

id = button.CommandName;

DataView dv = new DataView(dt);

dv.RowFilter = "id = " + id;

path = dv[0][2].ToString();

Response.ClearHeaders();

Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + path);

Response.WriteFile(path);
```

Not sure what is going on or why it won't open...

If I forgot anything or you need more info, let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what works for me:

```
byte[] fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/" + pathToFile));
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename);
Response.OutputStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
```

Comment: My path is a physical path on the client's server/computer so the Server.MapPath throws an exception since it is not a valid virtual path.

Comment: then get rid of the Server.MapPath and just put the physical path as the parameter to ReadAllBytes.  I just showed an example for if you had the file in a directory on your web server in your application.  The aspnet process will need to have read rights to this directory you are trying to get the file from as well.

Comment: I got the same error, "There was an error opening this document. The file is damaged and could not be repaired."

Comment: Are you putting in the path correctly?  Are you sure the aspnet process has access rights to the file?  Also, try setting up a break point after the ReadAllBytes and see that it is getting populated.  Make sure your filename ends with .pdf as well.

Comment: I've tried the path in several different variations now, and none have worked via asp.net. In regards to access rights, where do I check?

Comment: Step thru with the debugger and see what happens on the ReadAllBytes line.

Comment: Solved. Your method worked, but I still had an issue where it was adding a 0 at the end of my document, so I fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear it.